# context error while creating and using fragments for basic and expanded state of card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

### I'm trying to create a mini program with the following functionality:

1. Create CollapsedCard and ExpandedCard fragments.
2. Add CollapsedCard to MainActivity.
3. When you click on it, open ExpandedCard using MaterialContainerTransform animation, and return everything back when you click the button.

### Here is the code I have:

#### CardFragment:

```
class CardFragment : Fragment() {

    private var cardTitle: TextView? = null
    private var cardDescription: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false)

        // Настройте элементы вашей карточки (заголовок, описание и т.д.)
        cardTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle) ?: TextView(requireContext())
        cardDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.cardDescription) ?: TextView(requireContext())

        // Обработчик нажатия для разворачивания карточки
        view.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as? MainActivity)?.loadFragment(DetailFragment())
        }

        return view
    }

    fun getCardTitle(): TextView {
        return cardTitle ?: TextView(requireContext())
    }

    fun getCardDescription(): TextView {
        return cardDescription ?: TextView(requireContext())
    }
}
```

#### DetailFragment:

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var detailTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var expandedDescription: TextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)

        // Настройте элементы вашей развернутой карточки (заголовок, расширенное описание и т.д.)
        detailTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle)
        expandedDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.expandedDescription)

        // Обработчик нажатия для сворачивания карточки
        val collapseButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.collapseButton)
        collapseButton.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().onBackPressed()
        }

        return view
    }

    fun getDetailTitle(): TextView {
        return detailTitle
    }

    fun getExpandedDescription(): TextView {
        return expandedDescription
    }
}
```

#### Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate: Loading initial fragment")
            val cardFragment = CardFragment()
            try {
                loadFragment(cardFragment)
                Log.d("loadFragment", "Success")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("loadFragment", "Exception occurred: ${e.message}", e)
            }
        }
    }

    fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val cardFragment = fragment as? CardFragment
        cardFragment?.let {
            val cardTitle = it.getCardTitle()
            val cardDescription = it.getCardDescription()

            val materialContainerTransform = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
                addTarget(android.R.id.content)
            }

            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                cardTitle to cardTitle.transitionName.orEmpty(),
                cardDescription to cardDescription.transitionName.orEmpty()
            )

            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)
            transaction.addSharedElement(cardTitle, cardTitle.transitionName.orEmpty())
            transaction.addSharedElement(cardDescription, cardDescription.transitionName.orEmpty())
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            transaction.commitNow()
        }
    }
```

But when I run my application, I get:

```
Exception occurred: Fragment CardFragment not attached to a context.
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CardFragment not attached to a context.
```

If I understand correctly, my program has a broken fragment lifecycle, but I am unsure how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate any help and explanations!